# Позиционирование элементов относительно друг друга с учетом адаптивности

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Есть инпут, внутри которого справа в конце кнопка (здесь зеленый квадратик). По условиям инпут должен выступать за свой блок, поэтому задаю ему ширину 120% (или аналогично в vw). Проблема такая - при изменении разрешения экрана инпут тоже увеличивается или уменшается, а кнопка смещается. Как запозиционировать кнопку, чтобы при изменении длины инпута она всегда была в одном и том же месте инпута?

```css
.subscribe__form {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.form-wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 5.18vh;
}

.input {
    padding-left: 2.29vw;
    width: 34.58vw;
    height: 6.84vh;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #E3E3E4;
    border-left: 4px solid #4066A5;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 30%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background-color: green;
    opacity: 0.3;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;  
}
```

```html
<div class="form-wrapper">
            <form action="" class="subscribe__form">
              <input type="email" name="email" class="input" id="" placeholder="Type your email" />
              <button type="submit" class="button">->
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем конечно понимаю задачу. Но, возможно, это оно:

```css
.form-wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 5.18vh;
}

.subscribe__form {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.input {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 2.29vw;
  width: 34.58vw;
  height: 6.84vh;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #E3E3E4;
  border-left: 4px solid #4066A5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 2%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0.3;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <form action="" class="subscribe__form">
    <input type="email" name="email" class="input" id="" placeholder="Type your email" />
    <button type="submit" class="button">->
              </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Оно! Благодарю!)

Comment: Да-да, всё увидел, поменял, работает как надо)